How do you insert a map-reduce into a Polars method chain?
I’m doing a bunch of filters and other transform applications including a group_by on a polars data frame, the objective being to count the number of html tags in a single column per date per publisher. Here is the code:
120 def contains_html3(mindate, parquet_file = default_file, fieldname = "text"):                                            
121     """ checks if html tags are in field """                                                                             
122                                                                                                                          
123                                                                                                                          
124     html_tags = [                                                                                                        
125     "<html>", "</html>", "<head>", "</head>", "<title>", "</title>", "<meta>", "</meta>", "<link>", "</link>", "<style>",
126     "<body>", "</body>", "<header>", "</header>", "<footer>", "</footer>", "<nav>", "</nav>", "<main>", "</main>",       
127     "<section>", "</section>", "<article>", "</article>", "<aside>", "</aside>", "<h1>", "</h1>", "<h2>", "</h2>",       
128     "<h3>", "</h3>", "<h4>", "</h4>", "<h5>", "</h5>", "<h6>", "</h6>", "<p>", "</p>", "<ul>", "</ul>", "<ol>", "</ol>", 
129     "<li>", "</li>", "<div>", "</div>", "<span>", "</span>", "<a>", "</a>", "<img>", "</img>", "<table>", "</table>",    
130     "<thead>", "</thead>", "<tbody>", "</tbody>", "<tr>", "</tr>", "<td>", "</td>", "<th>", "</th>", "<form>", "</form>",
131     "<input>", "</input>", "<textarea>", "</textarea>", "<button>", "</button>", "<select>", "</select>", "<option>", 
132     "<script>", "</script>", "<noscript>", "</noscript>", "<iframe>", "</iframe>", "<canvas>", "</canvas>", "<source>"]
133                                                                                                                          
134     gg = (pl.scan_parquet(parquet_file)                                                                                  
135           .cast({"date": pl.Date})                                                                                       
136           .select("publisher", "date", fieldname)                                                                        
137           .drop_nulls()                                                                                                  
138           .group_by("publisher", "date")                                                                                 
139           .agg(pl.col(fieldname).str.contains_any(html_tags).sum().alias(fieldname))                                         
140           .filter(pl.col(fieldname) > 0)                                                                                     
141           .sort(fieldname, descending = True)).collect()                                                                     
142                                                                                                                          
143     return gg                                                         

Here is example output for fieldname = "text":
Out[8]:
shape: (22_925, 3)
┌───────────────────────────┬────────────┬──────┐
│ publisher                 ┆ date       ┆ text │
│ ---                       ┆ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ str                       ┆ date       ┆ u64  │
╞═══════════════════════════╪════════════╪══════╡
│ Kronen Zeitung            ┆ 2024-11-20 ┆ 183  │
│ Kronen Zeitung            ┆ 2024-10-25 ┆ 180  │
│ Kronen Zeitung            ┆ 2024-11-14 ┆ 174  │
│ Kronen Zeitung            ┆ 2024-11-06 ┆ 172  │
│ Kronen Zeitung            ┆ 2024-10-31 ┆ 171  │
│ …                         ┆ …          ┆ …    │
│ The Faroe Islands Podcast ┆ 2020-03-31 ┆ 1    │
│ Sunday Standard           ┆ 2024-07-16 ┆ 1    │
│ Stabroek News             ┆ 2024-08-17 ┆ 1    │
│ CivilNet                  ┆ 2024-09-01 ┆ 1    │
│ The Star                  ┆ 2024-06-23 ┆ 1    │
└───────────────────────────┴────────────┴──────┘


The issue is that instead of just passing a single fieldname = "text" argument,  I would like to pass a list (for example ["text", "text1", "text2", ...]). The idea would be to run the bottom three lines in the chain for each element of the list. I could wrap the whole polars method chain in a for loop and then join the resulting data frames, but is there a better way? For example to insert a map, or foreach, or other such construct after the group_by clause, and then have polars add a new column for each field name without using a loop?
What's the best way of handling this?
EDIT WITH REPRODUCIBLE CODE
This will produce a dataframe df and a sample output tc, with all four columns text1 through text4, summed and sorted, but not using polars for the last step.
#colorscheme orbital dark

import polars as pl
import datetime as dt
from math import sqrt
import random
random.seed(8472)
from functools import reduce


html_tags = [
"<html>", "</html>", "<head>", "</head>", "<title>", "</title>", "<meta>", "</meta>", "<link>", "</link>", "<style>", "</style>",
"<body>", "</body>", "<header>", "</header>", "<footer>", "</footer>", "<nav>", "</nav>", "<main>", "</main>",
"<section>", "</section>", "<article>", "</article>", "<aside>", "</aside>", "<h1>", "</h1>", "<h2>", "</h2>", 
"<h3>", "</h3>", "<h4>", "</h4>", "<h5>", "</h5>", "<h6>", "</h6>", "<p>", "</p>", "<ul>", "</ul>", "<ol>", "</ol>", 
"<li>", "</li>", "<div>", "</div>", "<span>", "</span>", "<a>", "</a>", "<img>", "</img>", "<table>", "</table>", 
"<thead>", "</thead>", "<tbody>", "</tbody>", "<tr>", "</tr>", "<td>", "</td>", "<th>", "</th>", "<form>", "</form>", 
"<input>", "</input>", "<textarea>", "</textarea>", "<button>", "</button>", "<select>", "</select>", "<option>", "</option>",
"<script>", "</script>", "<noscript>", "</noscript>", "<iframe>", "</iframe>", "<canvas>", "</canvas>", "<source>", "</source>"]


def makeword(alphaLength):
    """Make a dummy name if none provided."""
    consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
    vowels = "aeiou"
    word = ''.join(random.choice(consonants if i % 2 == 0 else vowels) 
                for i in range(alphaLength))
    return word

def makepara(nwords):
    """Make a paragraph of dummy text."""
    words = [makeword(random.randint(3, 10)) for _ in range(nwords)]
    tags = random.choices(html_tags, k=3)
    parawords = random.choices(tags + words, k=nwords)
    para = " ".join(parawords)
    return para

def generate_df_with_tags(rows = 100, numdates = 10, num_publishers = 6):
    publishers = [makeword(5) for _ in range(num_publishers)]
    datesrange = pl.date_range(start := dt.datetime(2024, 2, 1), 
                          end = start + dt.timedelta(days = numdates - 1),
                          eager = True)
    dates = sorted(random.choices(datesrange, k = rows))
    df = pl.DataFrame({
        "publisher": random.choices(publishers, k = rows),
        "date": dates, 
        "text1": [makepara(15) for _ in range(rows)],
        "text2": [makepara(15) for _ in range(rows)],
        "text3": [makepara(15) for _ in range(rows)],
        "text4": [makepara(15) for _ in range(rows)]
    })
    return df


def contains_html_so(parquet_file, fieldname = "text"):
    """ checks if html tags are in field """

    gg = (pl.scan_parquet(parquet_file)
          .select("publisher", "date", fieldname)
          .drop_nulls()
          .group_by("publisher", "date")
          .agg(pl.col(fieldname).str.contains_any(html_tags).sum().alias(fieldname))
          .filter(pl.col(fieldname) > 0)
          .sort(fieldname, descending = True)).collect()
            
    return gg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = generate_df_with_tags(100)
    df.write_parquet("/tmp/test.parquet")
    tc = [contains_html_so("/tmp/test.parquet", fieldname = x) for x in ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"]]
    tcr = (reduce(lambda x, y: x.join(y, how = "full", on = ["publisher", "date"], coalesce = True), tc)
     .with_columns((
     pl.col("text1").fill_null(0) 
     + pl.col("text2").fill_null(0) 
     + pl.col("text3").fill_null(0) 
     + pl.col("text4").fill_null(0)).alias("sum")).sort("sum", descending = True))
    print(tcr)



Desired output is below, but you'll see that in the bottom of the code I have run a functools.reduce on four dataframes, outside of the polars ecosystem, to join them, and it's basically this reduce that I want to put into the polars method chain somehow. [As an aside, my multiple (textX).fill_null(0) are also a bit clumsy but I'll leave that for a separate question]
In [59]: %run so_question.py
shape: (45, 7)
┌───────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬─────┐
│ publisher ┆ date       ┆ text1 ┆ text2 ┆ text3 ┆ text4 ┆ sum │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str       ┆ date       ┆ u64   ┆ u64   ┆ u64   ┆ u64   ┆ u64 │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ desob     ┆ 2024-02-10 ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 20  │
│ qopir     ┆ 2024-02-03 ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 19  │
│ jerag     ┆ 2024-02-04 ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 19  │
│ jerag     ┆ 2024-02-07 ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 19  │
│ wopav     ┆ 2024-02-07 ┆ 4     ┆ 5     ┆ 3     ┆ 5     ┆ 17  │
│ …         ┆ …          ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …   │
│ jerag     ┆ 2024-02-06 ┆ 1     ┆ null  ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
│ desob     ┆ 2024-02-05 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ null  ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
│ cufeg     ┆ 2024-02-04 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ null  ┆ 3   │
│ cufeg     ┆ 2024-02-05 ┆ 1     ┆ null  ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
│ wopav     ┆ 2024-02-06 ┆ null  ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
└───────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴─────┘

So basically, tag counts by columns ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"], then summed ignoring nulls, and sorted descending on the sum. Join should be on publisher and date, outer (= "full"), and coalescing.

it'd been easier to help you if there was a reproduceable example with simple input and output.

@roman I have included fully reproducible code example as an edit. I will test your answers against it and revert.

but what's your desired output? do you want text1...text4 to be columns in the result? if so how do you want to sort it?

Further clarified in text, with code modified (though my text1..text4 sums and fill_null may be a bit clumsy)

Is it not the same as aggregating the list of col() names at the same time?
fieldnames = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"]

(df.group_by("publisher", "date")
   .agg(pl.col(fieldnames).str.contains_any(html_tags).sum())
   .with_columns(sum = pl.sum_horizontal(fieldnames))
)

shape: (45, 7)
┌───────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬─────┐
│ publisher ┆ date       ┆ text1 ┆ text2 ┆ text3 ┆ text4 ┆ sum │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str       ┆ date       ┆ u32   ┆ u32   ┆ u32   ┆ u32   ┆ u32 │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ desob     ┆ 2024-02-01 ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
│ xikoy     ┆ 2024-02-06 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 4   │
│ wopav     ┆ 2024-02-03 ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
│ jerag     ┆ 2024-02-05 ┆ 3     ┆ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ 11  │
│ qopir     ┆ 2024-02-03 ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 19  │
│ …         ┆ …          ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …   │
│ xikoy     ┆ 2024-02-10 ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
│ xikoy     ┆ 2024-02-02 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 4   │
│ cufeg     ┆ 2024-02-10 ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 4   │
│ jerag     ┆ 2024-02-06 ┆ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
│ desob     ┆ 2024-02-03 ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 2     ┆ 8   │
└───────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴─────┘

pl.sum_horizontal() replaces the multiple fill_null / addition combination.

This looks mightily impressive you've condensed the whole problem into 3 lines! I just have to make sure I understand what's going on here lol. BTW you forgot the sort but that's trivial.

updated

pl.sum_horizontal() to sum aggregated columns.

fields = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"]

(
    df.group_by("date","publisher")
    .agg(pl.col(fields).str.contains_any(html_tags).sum())
    .with_columns(sum = pl.sum_horizontal(fields))
    .sort(pl.col.sum, descending=True)
)

shape: (45, 7)
┌────────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬─────┐
│ date       ┆ publisher ┆ text1 ┆ text2 ┆ text3 ┆ text4 ┆ sum │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ date       ┆ str       ┆ u32   ┆ u32   ┆ u32   ┆ u32   ┆ u32 │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ 2024-02-10 ┆ desob     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 20  │
│ 2024-02-04 ┆ jerag     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 19  │
│ 2024-02-07 ┆ jerag     ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 19  │
│ 2024-02-03 ┆ qopir     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 19  │
│ 2024-02-07 ┆ wopav     ┆ 4     ┆ 5     ┆ 3     ┆ 5     ┆ 17  │
│ …          ┆ …         ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …   │
│ 2024-02-04 ┆ cufeg     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 3   │
│ 2024-02-06 ┆ jerag     ┆ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
│ 2024-02-05 ┆ desob     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
│ 2024-02-06 ┆ wopav     ┆ 0     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
│ 2024-02-05 ┆ cufeg     ┆ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
└────────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴─────┘

Alternatively, if you want to aggregate all columns except date and publisher, you can use pl.exclude().

original
The answer depends a bit on how do you want to see the results.
If you want to have additional column each field, you can adjust your code a bit:

fields = ["text1", "text_original"]

(
    ...
    .group_by("publisher", "date")
    # you can past list of fields here and the name will be derived,
    # so you don't need explicit alias here
    .agg(
        pl.col(fields).drop_nulls().str.contains_any(html_tags).sum()
    )
    # leave only rows where some fields have the tags
    .filter(pl.any_horizontal(fields) > 0)
    # sort by total tags found in all the fields
    .sort(pl.sum_horizontal(fields), descending = True)                                                                
)

And if you want additional column with field name you can use pl.LazyFrame.unpivot()
fields = ["text1", "text_original"]

(
    ...
    .group_by("publisher", "date")
    # you can past list of fields here and the name will be derived,
    # so you don't need explicit alias here
    .agg(
        pl.col(fields).drop_nulls().str.contains_any(html_tags).sum()
    )
    # leave only rows where some fields have the tags
    .filter(pl.any_horizontal(fields) > 0)
    .unpivot(index=["publisher", "date"], variable_name="field_name")
    .sort("value", descending = True)                                                             
)

